# List assignment index out of range when deleting columns in a nested list

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested

I have a nested list with a couple of things in each list. It looks something like this:

```
itemsOnShelf=[[3,5,6,8],
              [2,3,7,3],
              [4,2,2,3]]
```

Each column belongs to an item, for example column one/position 0 is potatoes.
In my program I have a function to add all the items for each column and save them into variables, for example `potatoes=9`

I also have a list where I saved these variables, it looks like this:

`food=[potatoes, tomatoes, apples, peaches]`

I also have a function that will delete a column if the sum of items in it is smaller than a specific number, for example 11.

```
minimumNumberAllowed=11
smallestNumber=[]

def throwAway(thing,pos):
   for item in smallestNumber:
    if item==thing:
        for shelf in itemsOnShelf:
            for veg in shelf:
                del shelf[pos]
                print(itemsOnShelf)
```

Next I have a bit of code that goes like this:

```
for item in food:
       if item < minimumNumberAllowed: 
              smallestNumber.append(min(food))
              print(smallestNumber)
              for item in smallestNumber:
               throwAway(potatoes,0)
               throwAway(tomatoes,1)
               throwAway(apples,2)
               throwAway(peaches,3)
```

The idea is that one column (item) will be deleted if there is too few of it. My problem is that once one column is deleted, I get a "list assignment index out of range" error because now there are fewer columns and therefore column number 3 will not exist. This is a problem that prevents me from moving forward in my coding. I tried using `while len(itemsOnShelf)<=3` or with other numbers but what it does is it stops before the column is deleted so I receive an unchanged list. How do I fix this index out of range error so the record deletes and the index corrects itself?

edit: I cannot manually delete the columns because the number of items in the main list can be changed so I do not always control which column needs to be deleted.

Comment: Please provide any additional code you're using.

Comment: you've realized your problem! decrement the index of the columns to be deleted after deleting a column, so that index will be always in range.

Comment: You have to be careful when deleting things from a list you're iterating over. It's like cutting a tree branch that you're sitting on: if you cut in the wrong place, Bad Things happen.

Comment: @Van Peer I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @jane sorry, my bad; not good at explaining! you can go through the answers.

Comment: @Van Peer  Is there a way of maybe using some sort of counter to control the indexes? The answers are not very simple

Comment: There may be better ways to organize your code, eg you probably don't really need separate variables for potatoes, tomatoes, apples, peaches. It would make it easier to help you if your code was a [mcve] that we can run. At the moment, we can't do that, because`smallestNumber` is missing. Is it a list? In the `throwAway` function, I _think_ you shouldn't have that `for veg in shelf:` loop, but I'd need to be able to run your code to be sure.

Comment: @jane please share the full code if you still need help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With a list of [`dicts`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) you could handle your data and call them by their key name. Now after removing a value, you don't know anymore what exists in any position.

Your existing data:

```
itemsOnShelf = [[3,5,6,8],
               [2,3,7,3],
               [4,2,2,3]]
food=['potatoes', 'tomatoes', 'apples', 'peaches']
```

can be modified to a list of dicts:

```
m = [dict(zip(food, i)) for i in itemsOnShelf]
print(m)

[{'tomatoes': 5, 'peaches': 8, 'apples': 6, 'potatoes': 3},
 {'tomatoes': 3, 'peaches': 3, 'apples': 7, 'potatoes': 2},
 {'tomatoes': 2, 'peaches': 3, 'apples': 2, 'potatoes': 4}]
```

you could get the sum for every food-key like this:

```
total = {k: sum(i[k] for i in m) for k in m[0]}
print(total)

{'tomatoes': 10, 'potatoes': 9, 'apples': 15, 'peaches': 14}
```

and you could remove items for all dicts when sum is less than minimum allowed:

```
for i in m:
    for k in total:
        if total[k]<11:
            i.pop(k)
print(m)

[{'peaches': 8, 'apples': 6},
 {'peaches': 3, 'apples': 7}, 
 {'peaches': 3, 'apples': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already identified the problem -

> now there are fewer columns and therefore column number 3 will not exist

So, obviously the column indexes are no longer the same. Once you delete column 0 ("potatoes"), column 0 is now replaced with "tomatoes" and so one.

There are a couple of ways to tackle this, but they depend on how you use this matrix later on. You could leave the "potatoes" column in there and set all the values to 0, or a "null" value like -1, this would indicate it has been "deleted" but still leaves the matrix intact. If you did this all your index values would still be valid.

If you must physically delete it then you have to adjust all your indexes to account for the fact that column 0 is now "tomatoes" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary? You can even form a dictionary from your existing array and item names:

```
item_dict = {k: [l[j] for l in itemsOnShelf] for j, k in enumerate(food)}
```

or using numpy (makes for easier array slicing):

```
import numpy as np  # for convenience
itemsOnShelf = np.array(itemsOnShelf)  # lets us use numpy slicing---not necessary, just easier
item_dict = {k: itemsOnShelf[:, j] for j, k in enumerate(food)}
```

You can delete your items with something like:

```
def throw_away(key):
    if sum(item_dict[key]) >= max_allowed:
        item_dict.pop(key)  # remove the item from the dictionary
```

Your last part:

```
max_allowed = # some threshold
for key in food:
    throw_away(key)
```

Comment: Why are you using Numpy for a small amount of data like this? Besides, the OP probably doesn't have Numpy, and it makes the code even harder for new programmers to understand.

Comment: For one, numpy scales well so we do not have to assume it is a small amount of data. It also greatly simplifies the syntax for slicing arrays and doing myriad other operations on arrays. I would advise learning numpy early and using it often. The syntax is more natural, and it is almost always faster and more efficient for operations on arrays than using native Python lists.

Comment: Added a non-numpy version of building the dictionary and replaced `array.sum()` with `sum(array)` for vanilla Python implementation. I still recommend getting used to using numpy.